# Checking if the text is in array but not being an case sensitive in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

**Intro:**

So I've made a PHP Username checker if the requested username is in the array.

**Problem:**

The problem now is, if the code checks if the username is listed in the array, it is an *case sensitive*, is there a way to remove the `if (in_array($username, $special))` case sensitive?

**Codes:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Check Username</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="submit" value="Check">
      </form>
      <?php
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        # this is the Array
        $special = array("Admin", "Mod");
          if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
              if (in_array($username, $special)) {
                echo "Username not available!";
              } else {
                echo "The username is available!";
              }
          }
       ?>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the username name to be case *insensitive* (which would usually be the norm), when you create the array add the valid usernames as lowercase and then convert the post username to lowercase.

Something along these lines should suffice:

```
...
// Convert post username to lower
$username = strtolower($_POST['username']);
# this is the Array
// Create the array of valid usernames with lowercase values
$special = array("admin", "mod");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I mistook. You can use `in_array` like this.

```
in_array(strtolower($username), array_map('strtolower', $special));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt function preg_grep():

```
$a= array(
'alpha',
'beta',
'gamma'
);

print_r( preg_grep( "/BeTa/i" , $a ) );
```